# VBA Excel Run time error 438 / getElementbyClassName

Tags: html, excel, vba, web-scraping, getelementsbytagname

I'm a newbie, attempting to web scrape aspect ratio details from the imdb.com website.
I've plundered some code on You Tube and adapted it using inspect element.
The code opens imdb and runs a search by title but returns a Run Time error 438.
Ideally I'd like it to return the html of the top result so I could perform a further click the top result to follow through to the page with tech details from where I could get the aspect ratio information and paste it into a cell.

Unfortunately I get a fail from my Click instruction - haven't even got to the point of extracting the aspect ratio info.

Can anyone see where I've gone wrong?

Many thanks,

Nick

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
  If Target.Row = Range("Title").Row And Target.Column = Range("Title").Column Then
    Dim ie As New InternetExplorer
    ie.Visible = True
    ie.navigate "https://www.imdb.com/find?ref_=nv_sr_fn&q=" & Range("Title").Value
    Do
     DoEvents
    Loop Until ie.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE
    Dim doc As HTMLDocument
    Set doc = ie.document
    Dim sDD As String
    doc.getElementsByTagName("a").Click
  End If
End Sub
```

Comment: You can only Click an individual member of a collection - not the whole collection. E.g.  `doc.getElementsByTagName("a")(0).Click`

Comment: Can you give an example of what is in  Range("Title") and the expected result please?

Comment: Range title would be a film title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, addressing your code

1. You can use a shorter version of `Target.Address = Range("Title").Address`
2. You don't want the first `a` tag element. You want the first search result `a` tag element.

You can use a CSS selector combination to get the first search result `a` tag element as shown below.

I use a CSS selector combination of `.result_text a` to target elements within parent class `result_text` with tag `a`. The `.` is a [class selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Class_selectors).

This combination is known as a [descendant selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Descendant_selectors).

Using search term in sheet of `Red October` this is what the CSS query first result is:

[image]

It is a relative link with base string `https://www.imdb.com`.

Applying via `querySelector` method means only first matched result is returned i.e. the top result.

---

VBA:

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
  Application.EnableEvents = False
  If Target.Address = Range("Title").Address Then
    Dim ie As New InternetExplorer
    ie.Visible = True
    ie.navigate "https://www.imdb.com/find?ref_=nv_sr_fn&q=" & Range("Title").value
    Do
     DoEvents
    Loop Until ie.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE
    Dim doc As HTMLDocument
    Set doc = ie.document
    doc.querySelector(".result_text a").Click
    'other code
  End If
  Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Great! Was looking at result_text but trying getElementByClassName with innerText and getting errors. Will try this first thing tomorrow. querySelector method!

Comment: That works beautifully... I'm now going to spend some quality time understanding why!  Thanks so much QHarr.

Comment: Any questions let me know.

Comment: The bits I'll be looking into will be Option Explicit and Application.EnableEvents=True

Comment: Ah... well they are easy. Plenty of documentation on those. You should always be using Option Explicit - enable it under the Tools >Options > Require variable declaration.

Answer (score 0):

This line of code:

```
doc.getElementsByTagName("a")
```

gives you the **Collection** of Hyperlinks in your HTML Document. That is, it gives you ALL the elements that match your given criteria, if any are available. 
However, some issues may arrive:

1. There may not be any hyperlinks available - So there are no elements to click on.
2. You are not referencing any element to click. If you want the first one in the collection of found items, you could go with the index, as suggested. Else, you might look for another clicking criteria (such as what is its text or another given attribute).
3. Even still, a found element might not be clickable by your browser, if, for example, it is shadowed by another element.

Comment: Thanks - this is an important lesson but going through all the tags seemed more variable and arduous than the query selector which is very targeted.  Very much appreciate your advice.